# Java util Preferences constructors

Tags: java, preferences

I'm trying to understand how the different constructors for `java.util.prefs.Preferences` works, and not sure which ones to use under different scenarios.

For one, **does `Preferences` persist preferences/properties to file?** In other words, can I use this class to store preferences across runs of my application, or is everything held in-memory?

As far as constructors, there's only a few ways to instantiate a `Preferences`:

```
Preferences p = new Preferences();
Preferences p = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(this.getClass());
Preferences p = Preferences.userRoot();
```

The [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) for those constructors are as-follows (respectively):

> Sole constructor.
>
> Returns the preference node from the calling user's preference tree that is associated (by convention) with the specified class's package.
>
> Returns the root preference node for the calling user.

So I guess I'm confused about the relationship between different `Preferences` instances, Java classes (`useNodeForPackage(Class<?>)` ???) and the end user. So I ask: **what does each constructor/factory method do differently than the other, and when to use each?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

### "For one, does Preferences persist preferences/properties to file?"

Yes, the data is persistent. No it does not *necessarily* write them to a file. The method of storage is implementation defined, it could store them in a remote database, the registry or in an actual file accompanying the binary. On Windows the default implementation writes to the registry. *(This is written at the top of the API doc you linked)*

### "What does each constructor/factory method do differently than the other, and when to use each?"

```
Preferences p = new Preferences();
```

This is not directly callable as @ojota84 mentioned in their post, it is used by the factory methods below:

```
Preferences p = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(this.getClass());
```

This allows the `Preferences` implementation to return a `Preferences` object that is specific for given class and doesn't interfere with preferences for other classes. On Windows this typically returns a `Preferences` object which stores the keys into `HKU\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs\myapplication\myclass\`. In an XML backed file this could probably correspond to `<myapplication><myclass>-data here-</myclass></myapplication>`.

```
Preferences p = Preferences.userRoot();
```

This is similar to the above one but returns the root object for all user preferences. If you think of preferences as arranged into a tree. Then this makes sense. On Windows this is typically implemented with `HKU\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs\myapplication\`. The XML analogy is that you'd be accessing `<myapplication>-data here-</myapplication>`.

### Choosing between `userRoot()` and  `userNodeForPackage()`

In essence its a matter of preference (pun not intended). If you only need to store one or two keys, `userRoot()` will create less entries in your registry. If you need to write lots and lots of keys, then `userNodeForPackage()` is probably better as you avoid name clashes and other problems. You also get a clearer structure in whatever is backing your preferences, be it an XML file, DB or the windows registry.

Answer (score 1):

Take care that new Preferences() is protected, it is can only be instantiated by a subclass.

userNodeForPackage and systemNodeForPackage get the preferences from a path based on a convention described in the [API java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) that you provided.

userRoot and systemRoot are the nodes located at user path or system path, this is described also in the first paragraphs of the [API java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) that you provided

Comment: This doesn't address either of my 2 questions merely provides the same link that I provided in the original post.